# EntityExistsException Issue with Many-To-One, One-To-Many Bi-directional mapping with additional properties in Spring JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have a User Table and a Movie Table & Fav_Movie table which is primarily for joining User, Movie and have some additional fields.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "User")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @ToString
    public class User implements Serializable {
      @Column(name = "id")
      private String id;
      // rest
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      private List<FavMovie> favMovie = new ArrayList<>();
   }
    
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "Movies")
   @Getter
   @Setter
   @EqualsAndHashCode
   @ToString
   public class Movie implements Serializable {
      @Column(name = "id")
      private String id;
      // rest
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private List<FavMovie> favMovie = new ArrayList<>();
   }
   
   public class FavMovie implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private User user;


    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Movie movie;

}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
 public User updateUser(UpdateUserRequest updateUserRequest) {
       User user  = userRepository.findByIdAndActive(updateUserRequest.getId(), true);
        User newUser = null;
        if(isNull(user)){
            throw new UserException(Messages.USER_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        String[] ignoreProps = ModelUtils.getNullPropertyNames(updateUserRequest);
        FavMovie favMovie = null;
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(updateUserRequest, user, ignoreProps);
        if(!isNull(updateUserRequest.getMovieIds()) && !updateUserRequest.getMovieIds().isEmpty()) {
            List<Movie> movie = movieService.getMoviesByIds(updateUserRequest.getMovieIds());

            List<FavMovie> favMovie = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Movie movie : movies) {
                favMovie = new FavMovie(user, movie);
                favMovie.add(favMovie);
                user.addFavMovie(movie);
            }
        }
            return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

I am getting the error: **EntityExistsException**

> "message": "A different object with the same identifier value was
> already associated with the session :
> [com.xxx.user.db.FavMovie#com.xxx.user.db.FavMovie@17ad]; nested
> exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different
> object with the same identifier value was already associated with the
> session :

tried with removing & changing FetchType, Cascade, optional etc but without success.
I dont want to use @JoinTable, that doesnt fit my purpose.

can someone help me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Could you check where this `mappedBy` refers to
 `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

Comment: Could you please elobarate a little. And FavMovie has movie variable so it is referring to that.

Comment: In you User class remove the cascaseType.ALL and replace this.
      `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
      private List<FavMovie> favMovie = new ArrayList<>();`